# Notation for Random Bernoulli-Like Vector With Fixed Sum

Tags: r, distributions, random-variable, notation

I draw a random vector of dimensionality $k$, each dichotomous element of which taking on a value in $\{0,1\}$. The probability that any element will be $1$ is captured in the $k$-dimensional parameter vector $\bf{p}$, the elements of which are in $[0,1]$ and sum to $1$ (or are normalized as such prior to use). A special condition is that the random vector must sum to some value $c$.

If you're familiar with R, I  can obtain such random vectors in R for some $k$, $c$, and $\bf{p}$ by

```
v <- vector(length=k)
v[sample(1:k, c, prob=p)] <- 1
v
```

I am hoping someone can point me to a distribution that captures this. Ultimately, I need a **notation** to use to describe this succinctly in a paper.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Hi ndoogan, what is the structure of vector $\bf{p}$? Maybe knowing that could be helpful.

Comment: This looks like a draw from a multivariate Bernoulli comprised of non-identical (different $p_i$s) and non-independent (sum of $p_i$s equal unity) r.vs. Not a nice beast. This paper contains notation: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1874

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is immaterial that the $p_i$ sum to unity.**  The problem describes a sum of Bernoulli$(p_i)$ distributions and conditions on the sum equalling $c$, $0 \le c \le k$.  (I believe that is as far as we will get in terms of finding names for this procedure.) It is of course a discrete distribution. The nonzero probabilities occur at all vectors having $c$ nonzero components, each potentially with a different probability.

**Vector-like notation is convenient and in common use.**  To this end, let us stipulate that

1. $[k]$ represents the set of indexes $\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$.
2. Any vector $v\in \{0,1\}^k$ can be identified with the subset $V\subset [k]$ of indexes $i$ where $v_i \ne 0$.
3. The notation $p^V$ means $\prod_{i \in V}p_i = \prod_i p_i^{v_i}$, the product of components of the vector $p$ for which $v_i \ne 0$.
4. Let $q_i = 1-p_i$ determine a vector of complementary probabilities $q$.
5. Denote by $V^\prime$ the complement of $V$ in $[k]$.
6. Write $|V|$ for the cardinality of $V$.

In this notation, the unconditional probability of observing $V$ is $p^Vq^{V^\prime}$.  The probability of observing $V$ for which $|V|=c$ is the sum over all such $V$,

$${\Pr}_p(c) = \sum_{V\subset [k], |V|=c} p^Vq^{V^\prime}.$$

This is a sum over all $\binom{k}{c}$ subsets of size $c$.   There is no simpler formula for it for arbitrary $p$.  Note that $p$ alone determines $k$ and $q$, so nothing else besides $p$ and $c$ needs to be indicated in the notation.

The conditional probability distribution therefore assigns probability

$${\Pr}_{p;c}(V) = \frac{p^Vq^{V^\prime}}{{\Pr}_p(c)}$$

to all $V$ for which $|V|=c$.  In a context in which $p$ is fixed the $p$s can be dropped from the notation; where $c$ is also fixed it may be dropped, too.

Comment: I think this makes great sense. Excellent work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your answer allowed me to realize I didn't fully specify the question. However, your answer gives me everything I need to get exactly where I need to go. Perfect!